# Batch script that executes through the invoke process and logged into a file does not throw build errors

Tags: tfsbuild, workflow-foundation

I have a batch script that runs through a invoke process and is logged to a file. Windows workflow build succeeds even if the batch script throws errors in log file. I have setup error handling and batch execution as below in the images
[image: BatchScript in Invoke process]

[image: Error Handling for batch script]

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add exit code in your script and check it, then set build status to fail if exit code is not zero. And try the steps below:

1. Add the new variables (scoped to the sequence where you run the
   script) called ExitCode (type = Int32) and ErrorMessage
2. Click on the InvokeProcess activity and change the Result property
   to ExitCode
3. In the Handle Standard Output of the InvokeProcess add a Sequence
   activity
4. In the Sequence activity, add an Assign primitive. Set the following
   properties:  To = ErrorMessage  Value = If(Not
   String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage), Environment.NewLine +
   ErrorMessage, "") + stdOutput
5. And add the default BuildMessage to the sequence that outputs the
   stdOutput
6. Add beneath the InvokeProcess activity and If activity with the
   condition ExitCode <> 0
7. In the Then section add a Throw activity and set the Exception
   property to New Exception(ErrorMessage)

Details you can refer to this blog:

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/Part-15-Fail-a-build-based-on-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application.aspx

There is also a similar case for your reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aacc32f1-bc29-4a85-bff3-4be1a43542e6/build-continues-after-prebuild-script-fails?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: TFS version is 2015. I have set the exitcode /b %errrorreturn%. And as per the above images, I have also done the error handling. Only issue is, If I pipe the batch script execution to a log, errors won't fail the build. If the logging is removed, it works perfect but the issue is that it is difficult to debug the build or execution of batch file when required as windows workflow builds logs are not that good.